# Swapping limits when simplifying a hypergeometric function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, hypergeometric-function

I have been trying to find a simplified expression for ${}_3F_2\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,\frac{3}{2}\\2,3 \end{smallmatrix}; x\right)$. After manipulating the Pochhammers in the definition, I arrive at $${}_3F_2\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,\frac{3}{2}\\2,3 \end{smallmatrix}; x\right) = -8\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n{+}2}}{(n{+}2)!}\frac{x^n}{n{+}1}.$$ This is very close to a binomial series, apart from the extra factor $1/(n+1)$. To remedy this I use $\frac{1}{n+1}=\int_0^1dt\;t^n$ to write that $${}_3F_2\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,\frac{3}{2}\\2,3 \end{smallmatrix}; x\right) = -8\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1\frac{dt}{(tx)^2}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n{+}2}}{(n{+}2)!}(tx)^{n+2}.$$ It's now straightforward to evaluate the sum$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n{+}2}}{(n{+}2)!}(tx)^{n+2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-tx}} + \frac{1}{2}tx -1,$$ which gives that$${}_3F_2\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,\frac{3}{2}\\2,3 \end{smallmatrix}; x\right) = -\frac{8}{x^2}\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t^2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-tx}} + \frac{1}{2}tx -1\right).$$ This integral does not converge, so I have not been able to simplify ${}_3F_2\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,\frac{3}{2}\\2,3 \end{smallmatrix}; x\right)$ this way.

I assume that this is probably because I should not have swapped around the integral and the sum when I evaluated the sum using the binomial series. Is it true that the limits in the integral and sum do not commute in the case? How can you check whether it's valid to swap an integral and an infinite sum?

Is it possible to define something like a commutator $$\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty, \int_0^1dt\right]:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1dt -\int_0^1dt\sum_{n=0}^\infty$$and then compute this quantity to give an extra piece which adds to my final integral to give something that converges?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is simply to reduce your hypergeometric function, one way you can approach this is working with integral representations as opposed to directly working with the series expansion. Here is a CAS (Mathematica) assisted approach to reducing your hypergeometric function.  You may go back and fill in the details of how the integrals are evaluated if you're looking for a more detailed proof. This is simply meant to sketch out the approach for you.

---

Using [DLMF 16.6.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2) and assuming $|x|<1$ we may succesively reduce your ${_3F_2}(\cdots)$ down to ${_1F_0}(\cdot)$ by writing
$$
\begin{align}
{_3F_2}\left({1,1,3/2\atop 2,3};x\right)
&=\int_0^1 \mathrm du\,{_2F_1}\left({1,3/2\atop 3};xu\right)\\
&=2\int_0^1 \mathrm du\,\int_0^1\mathrm dv\,(1-v){_1F_0}\left({3/2\atop -};xuv\right)\\
&=2\int_0^1 \mathrm du\,\int_0^1\mathrm dv\,(1-v)(1-xuv)^{-3/2}.
\end{align}
$$
Evaluating the integral in $v$ (presumably by parts) one has
$$
{_3F_2}\left({1,1,3/2\atop 2,3};x\right)=
\frac{4}{x^2}\int_0^1 \mathrm du\,\frac{2-2\sqrt{1-x u}-x u}{u^2}.
$$
Evaluating over $u$ then gives the final result
$$
{_3F_2}\left({1,1,3/2\atop 2,3};x\right)=
\frac{4}{x^2}\left(-2 x\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{1-x}-x\log(x/4)+x+2\sqrt{1-x}-2\right).
$$

Comment: Thankyou, it's interesting to learn some new techniques for manipulating hypergeometric functions. I was able to complete my analysis above to get the same result as you by calculating $x\;{_3F_2}\left({1,1,3/2\atop 2,3};x\right) - y\;{_3F_2}\left({1,1,3/2\atop 2,3};y\right)$ which changed the limits to give a convergent integral in $t$, and I used Mathematica to fix the remaining constant. I'm trying to learn some analysis, which is why I asked the question about swapping the integral and sum.

Comment: @Joe Note that asking when we can interchange a series and an integral is really asking when we can interchange two limits.  What you need if you want to interchange limits is the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). If you can show dominated convergence then we have $\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty=\int_0^1\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\int_0^1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1$

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. Does that mean it's not possible to analyse whether you can swap the limit and integral in this case using the Riemann integral, and it's necessary to use Lebesgue integration? I thought it would be possible to understand this in terms of the concepts from an  introductory course on analysis